# Get Block contents from a Page in Sonata

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

Some colleagues and I are using Sonata Block Bundle in combination with Sonata Page Bundle. In our interface, we are able to open a page, then add blocks to it. Simple.

Now I want to send emails that include the page title and the first text block related to the page. I use `dump($page)` in my controller to verify that I have access to the page. I pull the title from the page via `$page->getTitle()`.

But when I try to retrieve block information, the `$page->getBlocks()` method just returns an object containing an empty collection.

I have verified that I can load the blocks from the page in the CMS, so I know there's a way to do it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$blocks` parameter of the `Page` entity is a realation, therefore by default is is [lazy loaded](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#entity-object-graph-traversal).

If you want to have `$block` always loaded when you load any `Page` entity anywhere, you can [eager load](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#onetomany) blocks, this is however not recommended due to performance impact (you probably don't need `$blocks` every time you load `Page` entity).

Another way if having the `$blocks` loaded is to initialize the collection manually, like so:

```php
$blocks = $page->getBlocks();
$blocks->initialize();
```

Then, when you `dump($blocks)` they should not be an empty collection.

In general the lazy fetched collections are initialized on the moment they are used, e.g. in a foreach - that's why it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I do this, I get `Call to a member function initialize() on array`

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where are you doing this?

Comment: I am doing this in a controller.

Comment: So before, as you wrote, the `$page->getBlocks()` dump `returns an object containing an empty collection`, but now it is an array? Have you maybe done the initialization after the foreach? Is there any code between the beginning of the controller and the `$blocks->initialize()` part?

Comment: It looks like that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a satisfactory answer, but I found that by iterating over the results of `$page->getBlocks()` in a `foreach` loop (rather than just using `dump($page)` to look at output), I was suddenly able to access the content of the blocks! Presto! Magic!

```
    foreach ($page->getBlocks() as $block) {
        $blocks[] = $block;
    }
```

If someone wants to give a more in-depth answer explaining why the application behaves in this rather mysterious way, I'll be happy to mark it as the correct answer.